# Stuck at a step of finding a conjugate $w$ of $f=(z^2)-2$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]How did we go from the expression to the second. From the first expression I can write $f(\varphi(w))=\varphi(w^2)$ but I cant proceed further.

> $\varphi^{-1} f(\varphi(w)))=w^2$ or $f(z)=\varphi(g(\varphi^{-1}(z)))$, where $g(w)=w^2$.

Comment: A little clarification needs here.

Comment: Its a pretty long question. i dont know how to type it.

Comment: done. now the first image is basically the question.

Comment: You have found it! But it's not related to conjugate  w.?

Comment: yes mate.Just realised .stupid of me.Thanks though

Comment: I think the question is wrong. The question should be finding a conjugate phi(w) of f=(z^2)−2

Comment: To be what? analytic? Harmonic?

Comment: I dont completely understand what you are saying.If you want to know this stuff go to week 2 lecture four of complex analysis at coursera.sorry.